# Can't analyze HTTPS traffic of docker container in mitmproxy

Tags: docker, ssl, curl

### Overview

I need to analyze HTTPS traffic of docker container in mitmproxy.
Installed mitmproxy on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server, and mitmproxy CA certificate using `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/`.

Also I configured mitmproxy to run in transparent proxying mode, with "Work-around to redirect traffic originating from the machine itself", as in official guide [here](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/).

My setup is as follows:

- I have two users: root and john
- john runs mitmproxy with following command: `$HOME/.local/bin/mitmproxy --mode transparent --showhost --set block_global=false -p 8081`
- iptables rules configured to redirect tcp 80 and 443 ports of OUTPUT chain to 8081 port of all users, except john that runs mitmproxy. Rules is as follows: `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner john --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8081`, `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner john --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8081`

### Example

So, root runs: `curl http://ifconfig.me`, in john's mitmproxy terminal I can see intercepted HTTP request, **nice**.

And, root runs: `curl https://ifconfig.me`, in john's mitmproxy terminal I can see intercepted HTTPS request, **NICE!**.

Now, let's run container based curl from docker hub. I pulled it with: `docker pull curlimages/curl`. And root runs it: `docker run --network host --rm curlimages/curl http://ifconfig.me`, take attention that I used `--network host`, so iptables rules will be applied to container. In john's mitmproxy terminal I can see intercepted HTTP request, **NICE!!**

And now, root runs: `docker run --network host --rm curlimages/curl https://ifconfig.me`, **TOTAL FAIL**, docker-based curl shows error: `curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a secure connection to it.`

As I can understand, this error means that curl doesn't trust mitmproxy CA certificate. But general curl utility works fine, mitmproxy intercepts HTTP and HTTPS traffic without any errors, this means that my setup is working, and mitmproxy certificate is properly installed. But with docker-based curl, mitmproxy is successfully intercepting only HTTP traffic, when mitmproxy trying to intercept HTTPS, it shows error: `Client Handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy's certificate`.

### Conclusion

I conclude that docker deamon, engine or whatever else, is doesn't using system certificate store, such as `ca-certificates` in Ubuntu. How can I make Docker container applications to trust mitmproxy CA certificate, so I can analyze HTTPS traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you did a nice dissection of the problem.

The problem is not in the docker daemon. That doesn't do anything to the traffic itself. The problem is that the curl in the container sees a different set of CA certificates.

You can either mount the ca certificate bundle (the one generated by the dpkg-reconfigure command) into the container or you can repeat in the container similar steps as what you did to add the certificate at the host.

Comment: Although, I'm solved my problem with different method, but answer is correct. I was thinking that I can avoid these complicated steps, but I don't see now any other solution for docker container to trust custom CA, except yours.